# How to fix: mysql_connect(): Too many connections

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error:

```
mysql_connect(): Too many connections
```

It has completely shut down my site, which has been running seamlessly for several years.

Note: I have shared hosting with GoDaddy.

How do I fix this?

ALSO: is there a way to close all connections and restart when on a shared hosting plan?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most probably, you have been a subject of a `DDoS` attack.

People [**on this forum**](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-200423.html) complain on exactly same thing with exactly same provider.

The answer is this:

> VB told me it was a DOS attack - here is their message:
>
> > This is not an 'exploit'. This is a DoS attack (Denial of Service). Unfortunately there is nothing we can do about this. DoS attacks can only be fought at the server or router level, and this is the responsibility of your host. Instead of doing this they have decided to take the easy way out and suspend your account.
>
> If you cannot get them to take this seriously, then you should look for another host. Sorry for the bad news.

A possible workaround can be this: if your connection fails with `mysql_connect(): Too many connections`, you don't quit, but instead `sleep()` for half a second and try to connect again, and exit only when `10` attempts fail.

It's not a solution, it's a workaround.

This of course will delay your page loading, but it's better than an ugly `too many connections` message.

You also can come with a some kind of a method which tells bots and browsers apart.

Like, set a salted `SHA1` cookie, redirect to the same page and then check that cookie and connect to `MySQL` only if the user agent had passed the test.

Comment: thanks for all the help...im assuming thats what it was...all the sudden it popped back up.

Comment: Excellent answer, resolved my issue. Additionally, for those who using CloudFare, they have a great tool for Rate Limiting; I've set it to a rate of 20 requests per 10 seconds, and it has blocked all malicious requests. I was getting DDoS'd in waves every 30 minutes, checked my stats and saw 60K requests coming from Israel. Adding the rate limit resolved my issue, along with the increase in max connections.

Comment: I have, regrettably, the same ISP.  The errors are sporadic but there is occasionally a whole bunch of them at the same time.  It's a WordPress set-up, so I'm going to install WordFence in the hope that it will block some rogue requests more immediately.  @Z41N, do ClouldFlare provide hosting or VPS, etc?  Last time I looked they didn't, or I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 24):

### This is a Technical Response

You will get this "too many connections" error upon connecting to MySQL when the MySQL server has reached its software configurable artificial limit of maximum concurrent client connections.

#### So, the proper way to fix this is:

1. Directly connect to the MySQL server, and perform the query: `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1024;` to change the connection limit at runtime (no downtime).
2. Make your change permanent, and edit the /etc/my.cnf (or similar) and add the line `max_connections = 1024` line within the `[mysqld]` section; then restart if you couldn't do the live change.

The chosen limit of 1024 was pure subjective; use whatever limit you want to. You can also inspect your current limit via query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";`. Keep in mind, that these limits are there for good use, in order to prevent unnecessary overload of your backend database. So always choose wise limits.

However, for those steps you are required to have direct access to your database MySQL server.

As you said, you are using GoDaddy (I do not know them that much), you are left out with the option to contact your service provider (i.e. GoDaddy). However, they *will* see this in their logs anyway, also.

#### Possible Root Causes

This of course means, that too many clients are attempting to connect to the MySQL server at the same time - as of the per configuration specified artificial software limit.

Comment: I have, regrettably, the same ISP (though once when I called them they didn't seem to understand that they were my ISP, and tried to intimate that the specific problems were caused by my home broadband provider - !?!).  I have checked that `max_connections` is `250`, which seems reasonable for a site not expecting more than a few simultaneous page loads.  The errors are sporadic but there is occasionally a whole bunch of them at the same time, which leads me to the other answer re DDoS.

Is step 2 always necessary, or just a fallback if the `SET GLOBAL` query fails?

Answer (score 5):

Do you close your connection when you're done with them? Are you using some type of connection pooling? Sounds like you're opening connections and not closing them.

EDIT: Already answered by Quassnoi. In the case it is a DDoS, and you're using shared hosting, you may be left with just contacting your host and working it out with them. Unfortunately this is a risk when you don't have control of your whole system.

Comment: so, at the risk of looking like a complete idiot...everywhere i've read says that php closes connections at the end of the script? other then that, im just using your typical mysql_connect()

Comment: Hmmm... you might have to try manually closing connections you don't need? What's the scale of your operation? Quassnoi might be right if you're not making an excessive number of connections.

Comment: yeah, its not a small site...kinda sucks...and i dont have access to PhpMyAdmin with this problem, and GoDaddy has my hands tied :(

Comment: You should consider switching to a new host. Go Daddy has made political contributions to opponents of Net Neutrality, and they have also wrongfully shutdown sites like seclist.org and ratemycop.com. My experiences with DreamHost have been good, and they're less sketchy as a company.

Comment: @johnnietheblack I believe you are somewhat correct.  If you use the [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class, this will auto-close the connection upon script terminatation, as the object owning the connection will be destructed. I'm not totally sure if this is the case if you use the non-OO equivalent function (in 2009 or 2023). The same PHP process may get reused by Apache if there's another request; Apache seems to keep them hanging around for a while; and it may be that cleanup only happens after several minutes of inactivity.  But this is just educated speculation.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that can cause this error is if the Database has run out of space.  I recently had this occur, and the issue wasn't connections, it was Disk space.  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: If your hosting account has a fixed limit on storage, it's definitely worth keeping an eye on the usage, particularly if your site allows users to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using mysql_pconnect().  Your host may have adding some sort of throttling for connections.  Like a maximum of 100 per 20 minutes or something weird.

Comment: -1. You would then be wasting a lot of connections on Apache children that are not opening the same database, or tables.

Comment: -1 also.  This is not an answer to the question asked.  There may be applications where a persistent connection would be beneficial.  But, for serving a web page, a persistent connection would surely be no better than a regular one.  Moreover, in MySQL, [opening a connection is comparatively as quick as a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479595/2511031).

Answer (score -1):

First, check your **database connections**:

```
 show variables like 'max_connections';
```

to check all **variables**

```
show variables;
```

Connect your MySQL server and update the connection size:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1001;
```

Comment: Everything you've written is already covered in an [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19686969/2511031).